# Existem altenativas para condições complexas numa expressão lambda?

Tags: java, expressões-lambda, java-8

Com expressões lambda é possível filtrar elementos de uma coleção de objetos, criando um stream de dados de acordo com o critério passado na expressão para o método `filter()`, isso lhe garante um modo de manipulação dos dados da *colletions*.

Também é possível especificar mais de uma condição na expressão, veja:

```
filter(pessoa -> pessoa.getIdade() >= 18 && pessoa.getGenero().equals("Feminino"))
```

Neste caso foram passadas duas condições, a primeira condição especifica pessoas maiores de 18 anos e a segunda especifica o gênero (neste caso, o feminino). No entanto, e se eu desejasse especificar varias condições por exemplo:

> Obter as pessoas maiores de idade do sexo feminino cujo a letra do
>   nome comece com a letra M e que more na cidade de Campos do Jordão.

Com varias condições ficaria um pouco difícil de ler o código e a condição ficaria muito complexa.

Contudo, esta é a única forma que conheço de filtrar elementos com várias condições. Eu gostaria de saber se existe outra forma de fazer isso, de um modo que o código não fique difícil de ler, utilizando expressões lambda.

---

**Segue o exemplo que ilustra a situação para que possa ser reproduzido.**

Classe `Pessoa`:

```
public class Pessoa 
{
    private String nome;
    private int idade;    
    private String genero;
    private String cidade;

    public Pessoa(String nome, int idade, String genrero, String cidade)
    {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.idade = idade;
        this.genero = genrero;                
        this.cidade = cidade;
    }

    public Pessoa()
    {

    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public int getIdade() {
        return idade;
    }

    public void setIdade(int idade) {
        this.idade = idade;
    }        

    public String getGenero() {
        return genero;
    }

    public void setGenero(String genero) {
        this.genero = genero;
    }

    public String getCidade() {
        return cidade;
    }

    public void setCidade(String cidade) {
        this.cidade = cidade;
    }
}
```

Código principal:

```
package lambdaexpressaoexemplo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class LambdaExpressaoExemplo 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        List<Pessoa> pessoas = new ArrayList<>();
        pessoas.add(new Pessoa("Dener", 24, "Masculino", "Cruzeiro"));
        pessoas.add(new Pessoa("Janaina", 22, "Feminino", "Campos do Jordão"));
        pessoas.add(new Pessoa("Marciele", 17, "Feminino", "Campos do Jordão"));

        List<Pessoa> resultadoPesquisa = pessoas.stream().filter(pessoa -> pessoa.getIdade() >= 18 && pessoa.getGenero().equals("Feminino")).collect(Collectors.toList());
        resultadoPesquisa.forEach(p -> System.out.println(p.getNome()));

        System.out.println("\nQuantidade de mulheres acima de 18 anos: " + resultadoPesquisa.size());
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sim, mas depende do contexto.

No caso de filtros, o tipo de expressão requerida é do tipo `Predicate<T>`. Predicados são nada mais do que uma função que retorna um valor booleano.

Você pode compor predicados usando funções `and` e `or`, por exemplo.

Então você poderia ter uma coletânea de expressões comuns ao seu domínio e compor expressões que se adequem às regras de negócio principal.

Exemplo:

```
Predicate<Pessoa> maior = p -> p.getIdade() > 18;
Predicate<Pessoa> feminino = p -> p.getGenero().equals("Feminino");
```

E depois a composição:

```
Predicate<Pessoa> filtroComTudoQueEuQuero = maior.and(feminino);
```

E, finalmente, o filtro:

```
List<Pessoa> resultadoPesquisa = pessoas.stream().filter(filtroComTudoQueEuQuero).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Em todo caso, algo que ajuda é a formatar e indentar o código de forma a quebrar a lógica em uma operação por linha. Geralmente é assim que vejo isso ser usado:

```
    List<Pessoa> resultadoPesquisa = pessoas
            .stream()
            .filter(pessoa -> pessoa.getIdade() >= 18
                    && pessoa.getGenero().equals("Feminino"))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 5):

Primeiro, está usando apenas uma expressão de condição. O fato dela ter sub-expressões, não faz ter várias condições. A condição continua sendo única.

Não me parece difícil de ler. Acha que seria mais fácil se estivesse em um `if`, por exemplo?

Bom, algumas pessoas não vão gostar disso, mas o que eu vejo que dá para simplificar é usar uma linguagem que preze pela sintaxe simplificada. Ajudaria um pouquinho.

O que poderia simplificar um pouco o uso da *lambda* em si, embora isto seja questionável, é criar um método que receba o parâmetro necessário e calcule o resultado retornando para a *lambda*. Sinceramente costuma ser desnecessário na maior parte dos casos. Eventualmente pode ter um ganho deslocando de local. Faz mais sentido se for usar em mais de um lugar.

Outra possibilidade é ter um método para cada sub-expressão. Tem vantagens e desvantagens.

Fora isto, não vejo como poderia ser mais fácil de ler a não ser organizando melhor:

```
List<Pessoa> resultadoPesquisa = pessoas.stream()
              .filter(pessoa ->
                  pessoa.getIdade() >= 18 &&
                  pessoa.getGenero().equals("Feminino"))
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Usando métodos:

```
List<Pessoa> resultadoPesquisa = pessoas.stream()
              .filter(pessoa ->
                  ÉMaior(pessoa) &&
                  ÉFeminino(pessoa))
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Syntax/ComplexConditions.java).

Algumas pessoas acham que deslocar a real expressão para outro lugar até atrapalha a legibilidade, já que para saber o que realmente está acontecendo é necessário olhar outro lugar. Claro que isto depende um pouco de cada caso e a maneira como está sendo usado.